# How to format a date in C# by example?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, format

C# provides a lot of flexibility when formatting a DateTime object for a string representation, however, one has to know all format strings to use that flexibility.

If you want to display a date in the form "Fri, June 24", you can do it like this:

```
DateTime someDate = DateTime.Now;
Console.Write(someDate.ToString("ddd, MMMM dd"));
```

While this works well, it's hard for more sophisticated formats, especially for a developer working with it for the first time.

I want to achieve the same results returned from the code above, but with this:

```
DateTime someDate = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(someDate.ToString("Wed, June 12"));
```

The date specified as a string could be arbitrary. Essentially the format has to be determined by first parsing the date somehow. I know this approach has limitations (localization is one), but for simple scenarios it is much more understandable. Is there some way to do it apart from implementing it myself? I'm willing to use third-party libraries.

Comment: I don't think the latter one is more readable at all.

Comment: How would that compute the difference between dd/MM/yy and MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: oooo this would be awesome, especially for end users.

Comment: Sorry, but `someDate.ToString("ddd, MMMM dd")` is clear enough for me...

Comment: Can you give us an example of a more sophisticated format?

Comment: The brute force approach would be to generate all of the formats you'd like to support ahead of time, then take the "example format", try to parse it using each of your formats, use the one that succeeds. If multiple succeed, you have an ambiguous input which might require an exception.

Comment: I find your approach rather unintuitive - just learn format strings, it's not that hard to pick up.

Comment: @David - It would compute it in all possible scenarios (where day is 13 or larger), and make assumptions in the rest of the cases. Convention over configuration - it would take dd/MM/yy as the default if called ambiguously.

Comment: @msarchet, it would be awsome if computers could read peoples minds and correct for thier context and limited understanding (or would it?)

Comment: @BrokenGlass I know format strings, but always find myself having to use reference, no matter what. Some devs would be worse than me.

Comment: @Slavo, wouldn't the energy learning the assumptions this framework makes and the defaults for ambiguous calls be better spent learning the format strings, or how to look them up?

Answer (score 14):

Usually I just figure out what the correct format string should be (in your example `"ddd, MMMM dd"`) and then store that as a constant somewhere in the application...

```
public static class DateTimeFormats
{
    public string DayOfWeekMonthDay = "ddd, MMMM dd";
}
```

then you can just refer to it

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormats.DayOfWeekMonthDay)
```

Comment: That wouldn't save you the time to look it up the first time, would it?

Comment: @Slavo, no but it would save you writing/configuring and maintaining code around an add-on to do this for you.

Comment: It wouldn't, but you'll never have to look it up again, it is pretty straightforward to look it up... here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Whilst this is a good idea, and good advice for anybody tempted by the suggestion in the question, is this actually and answer to the question?

Comment: @Jodrell No, it's not an answer. I implied that in my first comment.

Comment: @Jodrell: The correct answer to the question is "you can't do that". So I think @Jon's answer here is a very good one.

Comment: This is a good approach, improves readability for maintenance and very DRY / good for consistency.

Comment: It's probably best to declare it as a `const` value: `public const string DayOfWeekMonthDay = "ddd, MMMM dd";` so that it can't be changed.

Answer (score 6):

I can see how this may appear easier for the newer developer to work with, but there are a few issues to contend with in building a "date format from date string" function. I can imagine scenarios where such a function might fail, saying things like:

- You said "May"; does that mean dates in **June** should format as "Jun" or "June"?
- You said "June 12"; does that mean **June 5th** should format as "June 5" or "June 05"?

Now, you could explain to new developers that they need to be careful not to use sample date-format templates that are ambiguous. But this would require them to already understand how it *could* be ambiguous. They would need to already be thinking like the formatting function thinks.

This is why the date format strings are defined as they are - to be as specific as possible about the desired output format the developer wants/needs to produce. They prevent such ambiguities to the greatest extent possible.

If the developer will eventually need to "think like the formatting function" to get what they want, it's probably worth the time to learn the existing definitions.

Answer (score 2):

The strict answer to this question:

> Is there some way to do it apart from
>   implementing it myself? I'm willing to
>   use third-party libraries.

Is no, unless a third party has done this already, you'll need to implement your own format string parser.

I share the opinion of most respondents that the effort required to do that is utterly out of proportion to the alternative of simply memorizing the DateTime formats already provided (or referring to their documentation). But, if you did undertake such effort, you would want to implement an [ICustomFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx), and an [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) that would provide it when requested.

See the ICustomFormatter documentation linked above for an example, but your task will involve providing a `Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)` method that takes a string in the format *you* are interested in and uses it to turn the DateTime passed in `arg` into a string matching that pattern.

Once this is done, and you have an IFormatProvider whose `GetFormat()` method returns your custom formatter, your sample code would look like this:

```cs
DateTime someDate = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(someDate.ToString("Wed, June 12", new CustomDateFormatter()));
```

Comment: Guess what - out of curiosity I tried implementing my own formatter and format provider, but it didn't work. Reflecting the code for DateTime.ToString() revealed that you should always return a DateTimeFormatInfo object from GetFormat and your implementation of ICustomFormatter will never be called. Is this a bug in .NET or on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can work, how would you know if `12` was a day or year. I suggest that the encumbent ambiguity would actually be more complicated than learning the relatively simple custom format strings.

Have you ever worked with VBA and dates?

Comment: I think it could work if you fix just one day to use. Sepcifiy a special day in your library like 12 september 2011, which can't overlap in any format.

Comment: @Scorpi - you would need to use 13th day and 32nd year in order to eliminate all ambiguities - eg 13th September 2032. 12/11/11 is still ambiguous... is it month, day or year first?

Comment: @Gavin Coates I'm not quite sure how to say this politely, so I'll just say it. September is the ninth month, not the eleventh. :) HOWEVER, your point stands: 12/09/11 is still ambiguous as to which part is which!

Comment: You would have to have a date which is unambiguous in as many formats as possible. Unfortunately, it's going to conflcit: to indicate which is day, month and two-digit year, you need a day>=13 and a year>31. But to indicate whether to use one or two digits for days and months less than 10, you need a day and month less than 10...

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while I managed to find a [Ruby library](https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp) that does the exact same thing I was looking for. Since I wasn't able to find a .NET solution, I implemented my own utility, inspired by the Ruby one.

A spike supporting 4 common formats can be seen on github - [Stamp.Net](https://github.com/slavo/Stamp.Net). I'm posting this as an answer so that people interested in such a utility can get it from there and use it directly in their projects.

Please note that the current state just proves a point and is an experiment. No unit testing has been done. Your comments are welcome.

Some implementation notes:

The .NET framewok provides a very good way for one to implement custom formatters and format providers for types. @djacobson mentioned this in his reply to the question. Unfortunately, the DateTime class is implemented in such a way that you cannot use an ICustomFormatter with it. When you call ToString() with a custom format provider, that format provider has to return a DateTimeFormatInfo object, and the DateTime class doesn't call the custom formatter returned from the format provider.

This has been worked around by implementing a custom extension method on the DateTime class, which invokes the custom formatter directly. Users of the library don't need to bother with these details.